# Overlaying multiple trajectories on CDC Growth Chart in R

Tags: r, graph, line-plot

I want to add trajectories of other participants to the CDC growth curve chart. I followed this Growth function written in R: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2011/09/implementation-of-the-cdc-growth-charts-in-r/

I was able to replicate the examples without any issue. However, the examples are only for plotting one individual instead of multiple individuals. I do not know how to add trajectories from other individuals to this plot.

Here is the code for the growth function

```
#   (1) wac36   = Weight-for-age charts, birth to 36 months
#   (2) lac36   = Length-for-age charts, birth to 36 months
#   (3) wlc     = Weight-for-recumbent length charts, birth to 36 months
#   (4) hac     = Head circumference-for-age charts, birth to 36 months
#   (5) wsc     = Weight-for-stature charts
#   (6) wac20   = Weight-for-age charts, 2 to 20 years
#   (7) lac20   = Stature-for-age charts, 2 to 20 years
#   (8) bac     = BMI-for-age charts, 2 to 20 years
#   (9) bmi.adv = wac20 + lac20 + bac (for pdf export)

MygrowthFun <- function( sex=c("m", "f"), 
             type=c("wac36", "lac36", "wlc", "hac", "wsc", "wac20", "lac20", "bac", "bmi.adv"), 
             path="./Growth/",
             name = NULL,
             surname = NULL,
             birth_date = NULL,
             mydataAA = NULL){

    if( sex == "m" ) {
        switch(type,
            "wac36" = source(paste(path, "grafici1m.R", sep="")),
            "lac36" = source(paste(path, "grafici2m.R", sep="")),
            "wlc"   = source(paste(path, "grafici3m.R", sep="")),
            "hac"   = source(paste(path, "grafici4m.R", sep="")),
            "wsc"   = source(paste(path, "grafici5m.R", sep="")),
            "wac20" = source(paste(path, "grafici6m.R", sep="")),
            "lac20" = source(paste(path, "grafici7m.R", sep="")),
            "bac"   = source(paste(path, "grafici8m.R", sep=""))
            )
        if( type == "bmi.adv" ){
            source(paste(path, "grafici6m.R", sep=""))
            with(mydataAA, points(months, weight, type="l", col="red", lwd=2))
            source(paste(path, "grafici7m.R", sep=""))
            with(mydataAA, points(months, stature, type="l", col="red", lwd=2))
            source(paste(path, "grafici8m.R", sep=""))
            with(mydataAA, points(months, weight / (stature*stature/10000), type="l", col="red", lwd=2))
            }
        }
    if( sex == "f" ) {
        switch(type,
            "wac36" = source(paste(path, "grafici1f.R", sep="")),
            "lac36" = source(paste(path, "grafici2f.R", sep="")),
            "wlc"   = source(paste(path, "grafici3f.R", sep="")),
            "hac"   = source(paste(path, "grafici4f.R", sep="")),
            "wsc"   = source(paste(path, "grafici5f.R", sep="")),
            "wac20" = source(paste(path, "grafici6f.R", sep="")),
            "lac20" = source(paste(path, "grafici7f.R", sep="")),
            "bac"   = source(paste(path, "grafici8f.R", sep=""))
            )
        if( type == "bmi.adv" ){
            source(paste(path, "grafici6m.R", sep=""))
            with(mydataAA, points(months, weight, type="l", col="red", lwd=2))
            source(paste(path, "grafici7m.R", sep=""))
            with(mydataAA, points(months, stature, type="l", col="red", lwd=2))
            source(paste(path, "grafici8m.R", sep=""))
            with(mydataAA, points(months, weight / (stature*stature/10000), type="l", col="red", lwd=2))
            }
        }
    
    mtext(
        substitute(paste(bolditalic("Name: "), name), list(name=name)), side=1, outer=T, adj=0, line=-2)
    mtext(
        substitute(paste(bolditalic("Surname: "), surname), list(surname=surname)), side=1, outer=T, line=-2)
    mtext(
        substitute(paste(bolditalic("Birth Date: "), birth_date), list(birth_date=birth_date)), side=1, outer=T, adj=1, line=-2)
    
    points(mydataAA, type="l", col="red", lwd=2)

    }
```

The line "points(mydataAA, type="l", col="red", lwd=2)" is for plotting one person's trajectory. The way that it is set up is:

```
Months  Length
0       50
2       55
3       56
5       61
8       71
9       72
12      75
15      75
18      81
21      89
26      91
27      94
30      95
35      98
```

I would like to use something like this table with 3 columns - ID, month, length:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df7nm.png)

How would I be able to manipulate the loop within the function or overlay the trajectories on top of this plot using the growth function in R?

Comment: Do you mean that you already have a table like the one above, but with a third column indicating the ID, and you are wondering how to plot the multiple trajectories? Or are you asking how to create the 3-table column above?

Comment: I want to use the table with the three columns - ID, month, length - to differentiate each individual trajectory plotted for month on x-axis and length on the y-axis. The way the code is set up only reads the table with two columns for one individual (month and length). I want it to read month and length for multiple individuals for multiple trajectories to be plotted.